# Arduino Uno array fails

Tags: arrays, arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to flash colors using neoPixel and atm 8 led strip (will be longer later). What I am trying to do is give a list of pixel information and loop through the list and flash the lights as the 'script array' says.

Here is the code I have done so far:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif

#define PIN 6

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(8, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {

  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
  int array[2][8][3] = {
    {{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40}},
    {{50, 90, 200}, {50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200}}
  }; // flashing two colors on all leds
}

void loop() {
  fromArray(50);
}

void fromArray(uint8_t wait){
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<8; j++){
      strip.setPixelColor(j, strip.Color(array[i][j][0],array[i][j][1],array[i][j][2]))
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait)
  } 
}
```

When I check this code I get the error `'array' was not declared in this scope` from line `strip.setPixelColor(j, strip.Color(array[i][j][0],array[i][j][1],array[i][j][2]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` variable is declared inside the `setup` function and is only available inside this function.  You simply need to move the declaration of `array` into the global scope (outside the `setup` function.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif

#define PIN 6

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(8, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

int array[2][8][3] = {
    {{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40}},
    {{50, 90, 200}, {50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200}}
  }; // flashing two colors on all leds

void setup() {

  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
}

void loop() {
  fromArray(50);
}

void fromArray(uint8_t wait){
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<8; j++){
      strip.setPixelColor(j, strip.Color(array[i][j][0],array[i][j][1],array[i][j][2]));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  } 
}
```

You are also missing some semi-colons in your `fromArray` function which I have added in my version.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, both of you. Somehow that slipped in there, well. Time to continue with the photo frame :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you array is declared in your `setup()` function and is not visible to the rest of your code.

You should move it to the top.

```
int array[2][8][3] = {
    {{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40},{120, 100, 40}},
    {{50, 90, 200}, {50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200},{50, 90, 200}}
  }; // flashing two colors on all leds

void setup() {

  strip.begin();
  strip.show();

}

void loop() {
  fromArray(50);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, both of you. Somehow that slipped in there, well. Time to continue with the photo frame :)